# number of automorphisms for group in order 169

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group with order 169. Prove number of automorphisms is at least 143.

I thought that 169 is 13 squared so maybe G isomorphic to $ Z_{169} $ but I dont have any idea. How can I solve it?

Comment: A group of order $p^2$, for a prime $p$, what possible structures can it have? For each of these structures, what automorphisms do exist?

Comment: I am nor sure I understand. .. can you post answer please?

Comment: Hint: The elements of a group of order $p^2$ are all of the orders $1$, $p$ or $p^2$.

Comment: Did I do something wrong or can $143$ be replaced with $156$?

Comment: The orders of the automorphism groups of the two types of groups of order $13^2$ are $156$ and $26208$ so I wonder where the $143$ comes from? Perhaps it's deliberate and designed to confuse!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be prime and $G$ a group of order $p^2$.

If $G$ is cyclic, there are $\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)$ automorphisms.

So assume $G$ is not cyclic, hence each element $\ne 1$ has order $p$.
$G$ acts on itself by conjugation. The length of the orbit of an element $g\in G$ is either $1$ or $p$ or $p^2$. In fact $p^2$ is excluded beacuse $1$ is not conjugate to any other element.
As the $p^2-1$ nontrivial alements of$G$ cannot be partitioned into orbits of size $p$, there must exist some $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ with orbit length $1$, i.e. $N:= \langle g\rangle $ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.
Then $N\cong G/N\cong Z_{p}$ and $$1\to N\to G\to G/N\to 1$$
splits (just pick a preimage of a generator of $G/N$) thus making $G$ a semidirect product of $Z_{p}$ with itself. As $Z_{p}$ has only $p-1$ automorphisms, it has no automorphism of order $p$ and we conclude that the product is in fact direct. But $G\cong Z_{p}\times Z_{p}$ has at least $(p-1)^2$ automorphisms (from picking one per factor; we could easily find more by switching the factors).